# Can IKEA FRAMTID built-in microwave be installed in a 24"-wide cabinet?

Tags: microwave-oven

The [FRAMTID microwave](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/50182564/) is listed as 30" but its' body is 21.8" wide. It looks like it would physically fit into a 24"-wide IKEA cabinet, and appears to be front/top- (not side-) vented. I even saw it installed in a 24" cabinet at an IKEA store (w/o being powered on). Yet [installation instructions from Whirlpool](http://www.whirlpool.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Installation%20Instructions%20-%20W10335301.pdf) call for a 28"+ cabinet width - implying 3"(!) air gap on each side.

So, can I install it in a 24"-wide cabinet? Or would that setup not allow for enough venting?

Comment: I believe that the 24 inch cabinet sold by Ikea after it is assembled is only 22.5. The specs on the microwave are bigger. I am having same issue/question. Were you able to figure it out? Please share

Answer (score 2):

NO, you cannot install in a 24" cabinet. Minimum clearances stated in the installation instructions need to be followed or the manufacturer safety certifications will be null and void. If a fire starts because of improper installation, your insurance will not cover your claim either.

The "30" designation does not refer to cabinet size, it refers to the finished width across the front with the included trim pieces installed to cover the required 3" clearance on either side. The installation instructions will tell you to center the unit in the over-sized opening.

Comment: Absolutely.  I would like to see questions like this get a stock answer to the affect of "using appliances in a manner counter indicated by the manufacturer is never advisable." It's an engineering nightmare even for experienced cabinet makers. There's just too many specs to observe and getting it wrong can be disastrous.

Comment: I have come across microwaves sitting on top of their own cord and sometimes cause the heavy duty cord to melt and expose conductors. Now imagine that heat/energy but in a space tightly enclosed in wood/particle board!

Answer (score 0):

You can fit it! There are variations in what it needs. The side panels that make it fit into a 30 in cabinet are optional. (The cord is in the top left corner... so unless you do something weird, the microwave wouldn't sit on the cord.)

Upon getting the microwave you can take your own measurements, but mine were easily adaptable for the 24, 26, 28, or 30" cabinet. I assembled mine in a 26" wide base cabinet and it works perfectly there, even allowing space at the bottom For a drawer.

The 24" cabinet, you will be able to  slide it in without an issue. When you pull the front door down you will see 4 holes for screws, 2 on each side. Attach those to the facing of your cabinet. Follow the instructions for assemble and use otherwise.

The vent is on the front so the circulation of hot air isn't building up/ going into your cabinet.